# How to implement a "Visibility system"

Tags: unity-game-engine, entity-component-system

I've managed to disable animation on entities that are not on the screen. However, I'm looking for a more pure math based way of doing this (instead of the viewport point trick). Does somebody have any idea how could I effectively "Jobify" this code?

```
public class VisibilitySystem : ComponentSystem
{
    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        var dt = Time.deltaTime;

        var cam = Camera.main;

        Entities.ForEach((ref IsVisible IsVisible, ref LocalToWorld LocalToWorld) =>
{
    Vector3 viewPos = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(LocalToWorld.Position);
    if (viewPos.x > 0 && viewPos.x < 1 && viewPos.y > 0 && viewPos.y < 1 && viewPos.z > 0)
    {
        IsVisible.Value = true;
    }
    else IsVisible.Value = false;
});
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why? 2) No really, why? Unity already doesn't bother rendering anything that's not in front of the camera, so why do you want to spend CPU cycles doing something that will save nothing?

Comment: 1) "Why do you want to spend CPU cycles doing something that will save nothing?" I want to save CPU cycles by not running animation logic on those that are not visible.

Comment: Ate you sure that these animations are a serious performance problem? Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I can't provide a specific answer, but the general topic you're looking for is "occlusion culling". That said, make sure that A) this is actually genuinely a problem, and B) this is the optimum solution to your problem, because occlusion culling is non-trivial.